# Find and rename all png files

Tags: c#, performance, file, search

I have such problem : find all png files to disk and rename them as I did:

```
static void DirSearch(string sDir)
{
    try
    {
        var images = Directory.GetFiles(sDir, "*.png");
        images.ToList().AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(100).ForAll(dd =>
       Rename(dd)
   );


    }
    catch { }

    try
    {
        foreach (string path in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
                DirSearch(path);
    }
    catch (System.Exception excpt)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
    }

}
```

Actually a question : whether it is optimized enough ? Need as quickly as possible to process all png files.

Comment: There are 3 or 4 gazillion "rename" functions available so why not grab a couple source files and see whether you want to change anything?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all you should rename your function, it doesn't perform *just* a search then `DirSearch()` is not appropriate. What about, for example, `RenameAllPngFiles()`? More context may suggest a better name, *rename* how? According to which rules? That should be clear.

Parameter names are usually camelCase and they're not prefixed, `sDir` should then be `searchFolder` or even simply `path`.

You do not validate inputs. An I/O error or an invalid argument because calling logic is broken are completely different and they should be handled differently.

```
public static void RenameAllPngFiles(string path)
{
    if (path == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(path));


    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
        throw new ArgumentException("Path cannot be empty.", nameof(path));

    // ...
}
```

Note that a `null` argument and and empty argument are different (eventually `path` may even be empty to use current directory) and as such they should handled separately. First test is to throw `ArgumentNullException` instead of a generic `ArgumentException` if path is `null`. Second test may be rewritten to `path.Length == 0` but I find `IsNullOrEmpty()` much more explicative then I accept the price of the redundant null-checking (at least until I'll need `IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`).

We're now at the *core* of your function. First of all drop `ToList()` because you do not need it.

`GetFiles()` search all files and then you can start processing. If folder is big or you will change to include sub-directories then application will *lag* until operation is completed, you should experiment using `Path.EnumerateFiles()` which iterates file by file while search proceeds.

100 I/O parallel operations might be too much, you will find a balance only with real-world testing but a reasonable value may be around 4 (especially because each operation is very short and threading overhead may be too high). Not to mention that hardly  .NET scheduler will really start so many threads for your loop then probably you will not note any difference.

Do not catch `Exception` but appropriate exceptions you know may happen: `IOException` and `UnauthorizedAccessException`, anything else is a programming error that should be fixed during development. Also your second catch block is useless because function itself will never throw (you catch and swallow everything). Do not discard the whole batch if one operation fails.

```
var images = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.png", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .AsParallel()
    .WithDegreeOfParallelism(MaxParallelIOOperations)
    .ForAll(TryRenameImage);
```

That's all, note that you can pass function directly without wrapping inside (another) anonymous delegate. `SearchOption.AllDirectories` already search inside all sub-directories. If you do not have circular hard-links then it's way faster than your recursive implementation. If you need it to handle fine granted access permissions then code will be much more complex than this and you should definitely catch relevant exceptions (`Directory.EnumerateFiles()` will easily let you handle this problems case-by-case, see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5098742/1207195)).

Change your `Rename()` function to handle I/O errors:

```
private static void TryRenameImage(string path)
{
    try
    {
        // Your logic
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        // You may retry few times after a small delay,
        // file might be in use elsewhere.
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
    {
        // Log?
    }
}
```

See also [IOException: The process cannot access the file 'file path' because it is being used by another process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26741191/1207195).

If you write errors to console then you should use `System.Console.Error` instead of `System.Console`. `stdout` is for program output and `stderr` is for its errors.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. If I don't have access to one of the sub folders `Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.png", SearchOption.AllDirectories)` - it does not give exceptions? And then the whole search is finished. Ps sorry, my English is bad but I tried

Comment: 100 I/O threads was the thing that jumped out at me, too.  If they're all in the same directory, the rename system calls probably all need to modify the same kernel data structure (the cached copy of that directory's filenames).  Probably a lot of CPU time is spent outside the actual critical section, but a number of threads equal or less than the number of physical cores is probably what you should aim for.  So I agree that 4 sounds like a good suggestion.  @Lolidze, you might want to try 8 to see what happens on your hardware.  But startup overhead is an issue.

Comment: @Lolidze no, if you do not have access rights to one subdiirectory then it will fail. Also note that the same it's true for `GetFiles()`: if you do not have access to one single file then whole directory is ignored. Solution is incredibly more complicate that it should be (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5098742/1207195): use it with recursion and `Directory.EnumerateFiles()` + `Directory.EnumerateDirectories()`.

Comment: Hello, can you check whether I write [link](https://pastebin.com/FY4FgSa0)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. OK, that's original code...and?

Comment: i mean, I considered all of your edits and made changes in the code, all right ? 

I correctly call the function ?

Comment: oh OK! Yes you renamed functions and lowered number of maximum concurrent tasks, good start. Another important point is to change error handling (if directory enumeration fails because of one entry then I still want to go through all the others of the same parent, think about the root directory...) Also, now that I see the `TryRenameFile()` function, that's not a _safe_ way to do it, what if path (not file name) contains the string `hex` you're going to replace?

Comment: what's wrong with the error handling ? Take the EnumerateFiles function, it receives a list of files in the directory. If you do not have access to the directory , then my exception will not derail the entire operation. If file access is not, then the exception in the method TryRenameImage the same will not interrupt the entire folder.
Or I something do not understand ?

Comment: Well, catching everything you swallow any kind of error. Enumerating files and directories you should expect IOException or UnauthorizedAccessException. If anything else then your program should terminate immediately without iterating through all the files and folders of all drives...

Comment: Imagine for example that machine is running out of memory or that there is an error elsewhere in your code or your app is running sandboxed with some security restriction (security, not access privileges).

Comment: Moreover EnumerateDirectories() and EnumerateFiles() will fail if ANY of entries they're looking for cannot be accessed, you do not get all the others...you get nothing after that. That's why in my previous comment I posted a link to a workaround. About TryRenameFolder() again you should not swallow anything but ONLY IOException and you should apply a try/wait/retry pattern (see linked post) because file might be temporarily in use (for example by Windows shell to create thumbnails or some sort of indexer running in background or user...or...)

Answer (score 5):

The indentation seems to mix spaces and tabs, sometimes even in the same line - or, at least, that's the most generous explanation. Keep it consistent.

---

> ```
>     ... ForAll(dd => Rename(dd))
> ```

can be simplified to

```
    ... ForAll(Rename)
```

---

> ```
>             try
>             {
>                 foreach (string path in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
>                         DirSearch(path);
>             }
>             catch (System.Exception excpt)
>             {
>                 Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
>             }
> ```

What exceptions are you expecting to catch here? `DirSearch` can't throw any, and anything which `Directory.GetDirectories` could throw would be better handled by input validation.

---

The whole recursive structure is completely unnecessary. You just need to use the appropriate overload: [`Directory.GetFiles(string path, string searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thank you for your response. If I don't have access to the folder, then GetDirectories throws an exception and all work will stop, or am I wrong ?