# Archiving files into directories

Tags: c#, file

This program moves files to a backup directory, archiving them by year of last modification.

From a directory like :

```
.
├── file1.ext
├── file2.ext
├── file3.ext
├── fileN.ext
```

To destination:

```
.
├── _Backup
|   ├── 2002
|   └──_200X
|      ├── file3.ext
|      └── fileN.ext
├── file1.ext
├── file2.ext
```

## Configuration.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<data>
  <PathItem PathFrom="C:\Test\FjournaTest" 
            PathTo  ="C:\Test\FjournaTest\bak" 
            Delay="20" Enable="1" />

  <PathItem PathFrom="\\AAAAAAA\BBB\Commun\Email\XYZ\" 
            PathTo  ="\\AAAAAAA\BBB\Commun\Email\XYZ\Backup" 
            Delay="30" Enable="0" />

</data>
```

`Delay` is the number of days old the file needs to be eligible to the backup.

## FileMover.Cs

```
class FileMove
{
    private IEnumerable<PathItem> _pathList;
    private bool _Talk = false;
    private DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
    private int tryMAX = 7;

    public FileMove(string configPath)
    {
        if (!PathValid(configPath))
        {
            throw new Exception($"Invalid Configuration Path: [{configPath}].");
        }

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(configPath);
        var tempP = from p in doc.Descendants("PathItem")
                    where int.Parse(p.Attributes("Enable").First().Value) == 1
                    select
                     new PathItem(
                        p.Attributes("PathFrom").First().Value
                        , p.Attributes("PathTo").First().Value
                        , int.Parse(p.Attributes("Delay").First().Value)
                        , true
                    );

        //Distinct on From. 
        _pathList = tempP.GroupBy(
                            i => i.PathFrom,
                            (key, group) => group.First()
                        ).ToArray();
    }

    public FileMove(string configPath, bool talk) : this(configPath)
    {
        this._Talk = talk;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        if (!_pathList.Any())
        {
            W("No Enabled Path.");
            return;
        }

        I("Process Start.");
        foreach (var x in _pathList)
        {
            I($"Processing:\n{x}");//TODO Try > Catch > Log.
            Process(x.PathFrom, x.PathTo, x.Delay);
        }

        I("Process End.");

    }

    private void Process(string pathFrom, string pathTo, int delay)
    {
        bool ValidPathFrom = PathValid(pathFrom)
             , ValidPathTo = PathValid(pathTo);

        if (!(ValidPathFrom && ValidPathTo))
        {
            W("Path Not Valid!");
            W($"\tPathFrom:{ValidPathFrom}\tPathTo:{ValidPathTo}");

            return;
        }

        I($"\tPath Valid  >PathFrom:{pathFrom}\t>PathTo:{pathTo}");
        string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(pathFrom);

        Parallel.ForEach(fileEntries, (fileName) =>
        {
            ProcessFile(fileName, pathTo, delay);
        });

    }


    private void ProcessFile(string fileName, string pathTo, int delay)
    {

        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);

        DateTime lastModified = fileInfo.LastWriteTime;
        int DuplicateCounter = 0;

        var yearDirectory = lastModified.Year.ToString();
        string shortName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileInfo.Name);

        pathTo += $"\\{yearDirectory}";
        string savePath = $"{pathTo}\\{fileInfo.Name}";

        if (delay == 0 || (currentDate - lastModified).Days >= delay)
        {
            //Year Dir Exist ?
            if (!PathValid(pathTo))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(pathTo);
            }

            // Make sure that the target does not exist.
            while (File.Exists(savePath) && DuplicateCounter < 99)
            {
                DuplicateCounter++;
                savePath = $"{pathTo}\\{shortName}({DuplicateCounter}){fileInfo.Extension}";
                if (DuplicateCounter == 99) {
                     W($"\t\t[{shortName}] Have to many duplicate.");
                }
            }

            // MoveIt.
            int tryCount = 0;
            while (tryCount < tryMAX + 1)
            {
                try
                {
                    fileInfo.MoveTo(savePath);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    if (tryCount == tryMAX)
                    {//thinks 7 time before it speaks
                        throw new Exception($"-File move : {savePath} #Failed", e);
                    }
                    tryCount++;
                    continue;
                }
                break;
            }
            I("{0} was moved to {1}.", fileName, savePath);
        }
    }

    private bool PathValid(string path)
    {
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            W("{0} is not a valid directory or file.", path);
            return false;
        }
    }
    private bool PathValid(string path, out bool validPathFrom)
    {
        validPathFrom = PathValid(path);
        return validPathFrom;
    }

    public void W(string format, params object[] args)  //Warning always printed
    {
    #if DEBUG
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(format, args);
    #endif
        Console.WriteLine(format, args);
    }

    public void I(string format, params object[] args)  //InfoCut off if not talkative.
    {
        if (_Talk)
            W(format, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Several additions to the answer of @t3chb0t.

This

> ```
> private int tryMAX = 7;
> ```

should be a constant:

```
private const int TryMax = 7;
```

---

You should never throw an instance of the `Exception` class. Instead use apropriate built-in class or design your own exception. So instead of

> ```
> if (!PathValid(configPath))
> {
>     throw new Exception($"Invalid Configuration Path: [{configPath}].");
> }
> ```

you should use

```
if (!PathValid(configPath))
{
    throw new ArgumentException($"Invalid Configuration Path: [{configPath}].", nameof(configPath));
}
```

And here

> ```
> if (tryCount == tryMAX)
> {//thinks 7 time before it speaks
>     throw new Exception($"-File move : {savePath} #Failed", e);
> }
> ```

you can use `InvalidOperationException`, for example:

```
throw new InvalidOperationException($"-File move : {savePath} #Failed", e);
```

---

Instead of

> ```
> p.Attributes("PathFrom").First().Value
> ```

you can use `Attribute` method:

```
p.Attribute("PathFrom").Value
```

Also `XAttribute` have several explicit conversion operators so I recommend to use them. This

```
p.Attribute("PathFrom").Value
```

can be replaced with

```
(string)p.Attribute("PathFrom")
```

Especially it is useful when the desired type is not `string`. So instead of

> ```
> int.Parse(p.Attributes("Delay").First().Value)
> ```

you can write

```
(int)p.Attribute("Delay")
```

So all this code

> ```
> var tempP = from p in doc.Descendants("PathItem")
>             where int.Parse(p.Attributes("Enable").First().Value) == 1
>             select
>              new PathItem(
>                 p.Attributes("PathFrom").First().Value
>                 , p.Attributes("PathTo").First().Value
>                 , int.Parse(p.Attributes("Delay").First().Value)
>                 , true
>             );
> ```

will be simplified to

```
var tempP = from p in doc.Descendants("PathItem")
            where (int)p.Attribute("Enable") == 1
            select new PathItem((string)p.Attribute("PathFrom"),
                                (string)p.Attribute("PathTo"),
                                (int)p.Attribute("Delay"),
                                true);
```

Comment: ` throw new Exception`.. 400+ Matches .. In 3 weeks .. I guess I would have to name things.

Comment: @DragandDrop Good luck with it :)

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> public void W(string format, params object[] args)  //Warning always printed
> {
>     ..
> }
>
> public void I(string format, params object[] args)  //InfoCut off if not talkative.
> {
>     ..
> }
> ```

`W` and `I`? Yuck! What happened to the rest of these names?

---

> ```
> var fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);
>
> DateTime lastModified = fileInfo.LastWriteTime;
> ```

This is very inconsistent. Once you use a full type name and another time just the `var` and this interchangeably. Not sure which one is better? I suggest using `var` everywhere.

> ```
> private IEnumerable<PathItem> _pathList;
> private bool _Talk = false;
> private DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
> private int tryMAX = 7;
> ```

The same goes for the fields. Some of them are prefixed with an underscore, the other ones not.

---

> ```
> pathTo += $"\\{yearDirectory}";
> string savePath = $"{pathTo}\\{fileInfo.Name}";
> ```

We don't concatenate paths like this. You should use the `Path.Combine` method for this job.

---

> ```
> //Year Dir Exist ?
> if (!PathValid(pathTo))
> {
>   Directory.CreateDirectory(pathTo);
> }
> ```

This comment would be unnecessary if you named the variables properly. For example instead of `pathTo` you could say `yearDirectoryName`. The `PathValid` method is also not helping. What does it mean that a path is valid? Is it valid because it doesn't contain any invalid characters or is is valid because it exits? You should decide and use the proper method. If you check if something exists then call it `Exists` if you validate it then call it `ValidatePathDoesNotContainInvalidCharacters` but with all the `W`s and `I`s such a long name might be a problem I guess ;-)

---

> ```
> // Make sure that the target does not exist.
> while (File.Exists(savePath) && DuplicateCounter < 99)
> {
>   DuplicateCounter++;
>   savePath = $"{pathTo}\\{shortName}({DuplicateCounter}){fileInfo.Extension}";
>   if (DuplicateCounter == 99)
>   {
>       W($"\t\t[{shortName}] Have to many duplicate.");
>   }
> }
> ```

How does this make sure the target does not exist? It counts existing paths so put it a new method and call it `GetLastDuplicateNumber`. You should also craete a constant for the magic `99`.

---

> ```
> private bool PathValid(string path)
> {
>   if (File.Exists(path))
>   {
>       return true;
>   }
>   else if (Directory.Exists(path))
>   {
>       return true;
>   }
>   else
>   {
>       W("{0} is not a valid directory or file.", path);
>       return false;
>   }
> }
> ```

This method could be called `PathExists` becasue this is what it does. It doesn't validate anything.

---

Overall I find this code is very messy and contains a lot of misleading names and comments. You should work on smaller methods with precise descriptive names so that you don't have to write comments trying to explain what you code does. Comments are to explain why you are doing something, not what or how.

Comment: Damn it, you beat me to it. "Discard" it is.. :)

Comment: @Abbas I'm sure you've found something worth mentioning too ;-)

Comment: _"very inconsistent"_ How do you know my full name? It's because of this that I'm posting in CR. To apply the consistency in my every day work. So thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

Other answers already reviewed your code, I'd add a small change to your architecture. You already have a `PathItem` class (which you do not show here) to hold the configuration of each path to handle. Write it to be XAML-friendly and parsing will be pretty easy. This code:

> ```
> XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(configPath);
>  var tempP = from p in doc.Descendants("PathItem")
>         where int.Parse(p.Attributes("Enable").First().Value) == 1
>         select
>          new PathItem(
>             p.Attributes("PathFrom").First().Value
>             , p.Attributes("PathTo").First().Value
>             , int.Parse(p.Attributes("Delay").First().Value)
>             , true
>         );
> ```

Will then be:

```
var tempP = (PathItem[])XamlServices.Load(configPath);
```

Much easier and you get all the *power* of the XAML parser.

---

Now in your `Run()` method you have this code:

> ```
> foreach (var x in _pathList)
>      Process(x.PathFrom, x.PathTo, x.Delay);
> ```

Why do you need to expand `PathItem` properties as parameters? If *tomorrow* you will add a new property (for example a `SearchPattern` of a filter based on file attributes or both) then you will need to also add more and more parameters to `Process()`. Simply:

```
 Array.ForEach(_pathList, Process);
```

Where `Process()` has this prototype:

```
private void Process(PathItem pathItem);
```

---

You're using `Parallel.ForEach()` inside `Process()` to move files in parallel. Even if, at first, it might look like a good idea you should also **limit the number of parallel operations**. According to [How many threads Parallel.ForEach will create? Default MaxDegreeOfParallelism?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18943703/1207195) you may have a (variable) high number of threads but move operation is limited by two factors:

- Source and target disk throughput if source and target directory are on different drives.
- Kernel locks for cached file system entries.

In both cases a, let's say, 20/30 parallel copies are an *unreasonable* value which may end slowing down your copy operation. You should limit the number of parallel operations of `Parallel.ForEach()` to a much lower value (see also [Find and rename all png files](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/168950/13424)). I'd say to use the number of CPU cores as limit but in a [comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/168950/find-and-rename-all-png-files#comment320899_168953) Peter Cordes suggested to start experimenting with 8 then probably the double of the average number of cores of today's CPUs (and if he says so then I'd almost blindly pick that value as the best one). Things may change in future about cores but you will always have to face the I/O bandwidth (and, if you're not using SSDs, it's synchronous serial nature) limitations.

Comment: I can't wait to the max Parallel copy on our new SAN EMC!

Comment: Aahahhaahahha hit the limit!

Comment: The server admin hit faster than the server limit

Comment: Then he is Chuck Norris...